# Getting Android App's first installation date from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to get the very first install date from the Google Play Store for my app? I found several ways to get the download/install date of the last install or the last update, but I could not find a way to get the date when the app was downloaded from Google Play for the very first time.

Comment: Not sure if this helps.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime

Answer (score 1):

The way that I could do is making a real time firebase data base with phone number sign in that stores the first run date of the application.
It works fine but if the user uninstalled and reinstalled the application with a new phone number it gets a new date.

I didn't find another solution.

Comment: Something like this actually seems to be the only real option.